# Working with objects I found with Lambda Expressions in my List

Tags: c#, list, object, lambda

I want to change some attributes of objects in my list.

```
if (Space_Resources.List_Of_Buildings.Exists(x => x.Name == "Landing Pad"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("already there!");                    
                }
```

I can find my object which "Name" attribute is "Landing Pad", but how do I change the attribute "Amount"?
I can't use "x.Amount += 1" or something like that.

Perhaps you have way better ideas for me how to add some "Landin Pads" to the list without having multiple Landing pad objects? At the moment my "Landing Pad" has a static int amount which I want to use (and increase with 2nd, 3rd, ...) for all LP's.

Comment: you should get a reference via `First`, `Single`, `Where`, etc. and update them.

Comment: I don't know what you store in list - I don't know even if your list is a list - please add more code to see context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming there is only one element with the name "Landing Pad"

```
var entity = Space_Resources.List_Of_Buildings.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Landing Pad");

if (entity != null) { entity.Amount += 1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

check out some tutorials for "LINQ", because it is something very basic (and your class names and properties are not following the standard c# naming convention)

```cs
// assuming there are multiple landing pads possible
foreach(var building in Space_Resources.List_Of_Buildings.Where(x=>x.Name == "Landing Pad")
{
    building.Amount += 1:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is a rather interesting way to tackle a situation like this. But I would use something simple like this.

```
    var lsSample = new List<SampleItem>();

    lsSample.Add(new SampleItem { Name = "Sample Item A" });
    lsSample.Add(new SampleItem { Name = "Sample Item B" });
    lsSample.Add(new SampleItem { Name = "Sample Item C" });

    foreach (var item in lsSample.Where(x => x.Name == "Sample Item A"))
    {
        item.Amount += 1;
    }
```

you could also achieve the same results with just LINQ

```
        lsSample.Where(x => x.Name == "Sample Item A").Select((item) =>
        {
            item.Amount++;
            return item;

        }).ToList();
```